# How to enable cta-full-xpath-checking feature in xerces c?

Tags: c++, xpath, xsd, xerces, xerces-c

I'm using xerces c++ 3.2.0 to validate XML against XSD 1.1

According to its [docs](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/faq-xs.html#faq-2), xerces uses a subset of XPath 2.0 instead of full XPath checking, so I need to "enable a certain xerces feature"

This feature:

`http://apache.org/xml/features/validation/cta-full-xpath-checking`

Which I couldn't find it in `XMLUni` so I created it myself:

```
parser = XMLReaderFactory::createXMLReader();
parser->setFeature(L"http://apache.org/xml/features/validation/cta-full-xpath-checking", true);
```

Now when I run my code it crashes:

> Unhandled exception at 0xXXXXXXXX in XXXXXX.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: xercesc_3_2::SAXNotRecognizedException at memory location 0xXXXXXXXX.

It gets the same result as if I run:

```
parser = XMLReaderFactory::createXMLReader();
parser->setFeature(L"banana gun!", true);
```

If I comment out the last line, it will work but does not use full XPath checking (i.e. no Assertion)

What am I missing here?

---

*Note that if I set other features (like schema-full-checking) this way*

```
parser = XMLReaderFactory::createXMLReader();
parser->setFeature(L"http://apache.org/xml/features/validation/schema-full-checking", true);
```

*it works, the same result as:*

```
parser = XMLReaderFactory::createXMLReader();
parser->setFeature(XMLUni::fgXercesSchemaFullChecking, true);
```

*but not with cta-full-xpath-checking feature*. why?